# Find all real, periodic solutions of the equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all real , periodic solutions of the equation

$y(n+1) = y(n)^2, n \in \mathbf{N}$

My effort:
Substitute $y(n+1) = y(n) = \hat{y}$, to find the equilibrium to get the periodic solutions. $\text{Hence, } \hat{y} \equiv c. \text{We get }c = c^2 $. Thus the real periodic solutions are given by $c(1-c)=0$ when $\hat{y}_1=0 \text{and } \hat{y}_2=1$.

Since, $y(0)=y(1)=y(2)=...=y(n)$ when $y_1(0)=0 \text{ and } y_2(0)=1$. You will get a periodic solution set with $\{0,0,0,0,0,...,0\} \text{ and } \{1,1,1,1,1,...,1\}$.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: you have only determined what are the solutions that are $1$-periodic. Maybe there are solutions that are $2$-periodic or $3$-periodic or ...

Comment: Well, the first period is given by $y(n+1)=y(n)^2$, \text{ second } $y(n+2)=y(n+1)^2=y(n)^4$, repeat this many times you get $y(n)=y(0)^2n$, does this mean that all periodic solutions are the same?